# ONE specific delete clause doesn't work

Tags: php, sql

This delete clause doesn't work on my PHP scripts, but my other delete clause works. When I even run the query using phpMyAdmin it works. I can't see any syntax error; what's going wrong?

```
$sql = mysql_query("delete from tbl_albums where album_id = '6'");
if($sql)
{
    system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg("../assets/images/gallery/".$id));
}
else
{
    echo '<script>alert("Failed to delete album");</script>';
}
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? Why do you have quotes around that `6`?

Comment: It only alert "Failed to delete album", the qoutes is works fine with my other delete clause, but i also tried to execute it without quotes

"delete from tbl_albums where album_id = 6"

but it also alerts the failed to delete album noti.

Comment: What **MySQL** error are you getting?

Comment: THere is no sql error being returned,

Comment: No, it's your responsibility to print it out or log it. Do that.

Comment: http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: Check `$res_sql = mysql_num_rows($sql);`

Comment: @fedorqui: `$sql` is false after the query...

Comment: **What is the MySQL Error???**

Comment: It seems like $sql is returned with nothing..

mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given showed when i try mysql_num_rows($sql)

Comment: Did you previously connect to the database?

Comment: yes i did connect to my database, because my other sql function works fine.

Comment: Can you post the full code? @ramobrero Try replacing the code with my answer and let us know what you are getting?

Comment: Also, let us know the database dump... :)

Comment: my bad, i was editing an old script, with a differnt databse. i really need some sleep. THANK YOU GUYS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("delete from tbl_albums where album_id = '6'");
if($sql)
{
    system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg("../assets/images/gallery/".$id));
}
else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

And based on the error, you need to amend your SQL Script. Most probably, the issue would have been because of wrong column name or something else. You need to say what is the error here, so that we can try solving the issue.

Comment: my bad, i was editing an old script, with a differnt databse. i really need some sleep. THANK YOU GUYS!

Answer (score 0):

The function you're using to execute your query is deprecated and you'd be well advised to read up on and understand best practice for using SQL in modern PHP before continuing. If you are going to use the `mysql_` family of functions, though, you should know that after an error, [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns `false` and calling [`mysql_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) will give you as text the error returned by the database, which you can then log or print. Just doing this will most likely let you trivially solve your problem.

Most likely explanations: the table doesn't exist, the column doesn't exist, you're violating a constraint by deleting the row, or a trigger is being fired after the delete which causes some other error.